# How to effectively measure the performance of neural network if the data is noisy

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

If I have a noisy data, the `r2 score` on `(y_true,y_pred)` cannot effectively measure the performance of my neural network.

Suppose we have a really noisy `y=x^2` relation

```
import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(0,50,5000)
Y = X**2 +np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=1000, size=(5000))
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

Then we use the following simple neural network to try figuring out the x and y relationship.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=101)

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,1)
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(-1,1)

x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

x_scaler.fit(X_train)
y_scaler.fit(Y_train)

X_train_norm = x_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_norm = x_scaler.transform(X_test)

Y_train_norm = y_scaler.transform(Y_train)
Y_test_norm = y_scaler.transform(Y_test)

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
dense1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense2 = Dense(10,activation='relu')(dense1)
output_layer = Dense(1)(dense2)
model = Model(input_layer,output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_absolute_error')

history = model.fit(X_train_norm,Y_train_norm, validation_data=(X_test_norm,Y_test_norm),epochs=50,batch_size=10)
```

---

### Result

```
plt.scatter(Y_test,Y_pred)
plt.title('Practical Y_true vs Y_pred')
plt.xlabel('Practical Y_true')
plt.ylabel('Y_pred')
```

[image]

Apparently, the `y_true` vs `y_pred` graph doesn't look good. And the r2 score is only `r2 score = 0.306`. However, the `y_true` that we observe in real life is the noisy `y`

Despite the seemingly poor performance, our neural network is able to find out the `y=x^2` relationship quite well with an excellent `r2 score = 0.997` if we consider the following code.

```
plt.scatter(X_test**2,Y_pred)
plt.title('Ground Y_true vs Y_pred')
plt.xlabel('Ground Y_true')
plt.ylabel('Y_pred')
```

[image]

Of course, it is impossible to get the `ground y_true value` in real life and we are only able to observe the noisy `practical y_true`. But my point is:

> Did we miss out a lot of good models due to noisy y_true from noisy data, and due to the fact that we are unable to measure our model performance correctly?

Answer (score 2):

First don't forget to consider `y_scaler.inverse_transform` after your predictions.
If you don't apply this, you'll compare the output of the network, which is "scaled" and the true input which is not.
Here what you got using :

```
Y_pred=model.predict(X_test_norm)
plt.scatter(X_test,y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_pred))
```

[image: y_true,y_pred with inverse_transform]

Considering the r2 score, it's low **because** you are learning with noisy data. The NN will fit `x=y**2` and not `x=y**2+noise`. Particularly with the `adam` which is design for noisy data. This is why the r2 is so low, but it doesn't mean that your model is wrong. The r2 score is getting closer while the model perfectly fit the data, which lead to overfitting. To avoid this : Check that the metric is similar between the training set and the test set.

Finnaly you can't use the `r2` as an indication of the performances of your model. Use the cross-validation instead.

[image: fitting]

ps : you should consider `mean_squared_error` instead of `mean_absolute_error`

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = np.linspace(0,50,5000)
Y = X**2 +np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=1000, size=(5000))

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=101)

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,1)
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(-1,1)

x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_train_norm = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
Y_train_norm = y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_train)

X_test_norm = x_scaler.transform(X_test)
Y_test_norm = y_scaler.transform(Y_test)

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
dense1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense2 = Dense(10,activation='relu')(dense1)
output_layer = Dense(1)(dense2)
model = Model(input_layer,output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(X_train_norm,Y_train_norm, validation_data=(X_test_norm,Y_test_norm),epochs=5,batch_size=32)


Y_pred=model.predict(X_test_norm)
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.scatter(X_test,y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_pred))
#plt.scatter(Y_test,y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_pred))
plt.show()
```